# Database for replication or simple transferring data

Tags: sqlite, database-design, nosql, relational-database, replication

I will try to describe my problem of choosing good technology.

I have many machines which stores data locally in database. And there is one client machine with its own database. What I need is to pull data from all machines and put in client's database.
For now I have started implementing some RPC, but I don't know if its good idea. Because I need to manually take care of each table. Database is SQLite.

What is better. Making some RPC calls or find some light database with replication? Maybe NoSQL db like MonoDB?

Comment: I have a very similar setup as you have. Are you planning to pull some specific data from the other databases, or just get them all and their data and put into you client databases?

Comment: I could say all data (10 tables as far)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar setup where I have a couple of servers that collect various statistics and store in a sqlite3 database. Combining them is really easy. I have a python script that connect to each server, downloads each database file into a temporary folder. I then open the first one, and use ATTACH for each file, and then insert * for each table to merge in all the other databases into a combined database:

```
conn = connect('/tmp/database1.sl3');
curs = conn.cursor();

mergeDatabases(curs, 8);

def mergeDatabases(curs, j):
    for i in range(2, j):
            print "merge in database%d" %i
            print "ATTACH '/tmp/database%d.sl3' AS foo%d;" %(i,i)
            curs.execute("ATTACH '/tmp/database%d.sl3' AS foo%d;" %(i,i))      
            curs.execute("insert into db select * from foo%d.db;" %i)
            curs.execute("insert into vars select * from foo%d.vars;" %i)

            curs.execute("detach foo%d;" %i)
```

Comment: And after merge you need to clear server database before next merge? So not to download entire already downloaded data?

Comment: If you prefer. Thats what I do, as I now anyway have the database file locally, I don't need it on the server. In my case server space is also limited.

Comment: How I can lock database before copying it, so other process can't write to it?